# How to exclude some keywords from a search with Search API?

Tags: search

I can't find how to do boolean search, and ignore some keywords from a search.

I would like to do a search like `"house+garden" - parking`, which return all the nodes containing house, and garder as keywords, but not parking.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "custom_search" module can do that. http://drupal.org/project/custom_search

Although I don't know whether the exact boolean syntax is used, I know the module offers two ways to search in the way you want:

- With three different text fields (one for OR, one for AND, and one
  for WITHOUT)
- With one text field (By using some kind of syntax like
  you described)

Answer (score 2):

Custom search module http://drupal.org/project/custom_search works for me. What you mentioned above is Boolean search.